# Svn with LDAP authentication and authLDAPURL structure

Tags: svn, authentication, ldap

I need your help about SVN servers. I want to authenticate my server with LDAP. I need the **AuthLDAPURL** syntax structure. What do the keywords `dc`, `ou` and so on mean? Could anybody write the **AuthLDAPURL** structure like this:

> AuthLDAPURL "ldap:// ..... /"

What should be in between the slashes? What should I write after **AuthName**? The name of my server or something else? Please help.

Comment: Ask about this your LDAP-admin

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your LDAP structure.

It should look something like this:

```
cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
```

You need to ask your LDAP administrator for the basic access and authentication (It will probably include password as well).